# Invert part of the image color with CSS

Tags: css

I have an image with 3 colors: black, white, and purple. When inverted the purple turns green, how can I keep the purple and let black invert to white and white into black?[image]

```
.dark-mode .invert {
    -webkit-filter: invert(1);
   filter: invert(1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: By only applying the relevant rules to the right-hand half of the image. You'll need to share your full code for us to be able to help further.

Comment: A simpler solution could be to have two images of the colors you want and just swap between them.

Comment: @ObsidianAge there is no more code, just that when class dark-mode is added invert the image. When inverted it inverts fine however I want the purple to remain purple instead of turning green.